# Unable to re-install the windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have installed c# windows service using **`InstallUtill.exe`** command.Because of some error, service got disabled.
So I tried to enable the service changing its **Start up type** to **"Automatic"**using service.msc. But still it does not get enabled.So i uninstall the service using **`InstallUtill.exe`**.After service get uninstalled still it shows in `services.msc`.
So what I did was, I opened the **windows registry** and deleted entry of specified service.< BR/>
Then I tried to re install the service.But couldn't install the service.the message was,**"The specified service has been marked for deletion"**.When I check the services.msc again service is still showing. but in the description tab following message is showing.**"Failed to read description Error Code:2"**.

Can somebody help me to re install the windows service?

Comment: close services.msc and open it again and check, restart the computer before install it again

Comment: I already close and reopen the service.msc. but still didn't restart the pc. because it is the main server of the company.is there any alternate other than restarting..

Comment: you need to restart the pc as the service will be completely uninstalled only on reboot.

Comment: ok..ill do that .. but FYI..  i have uninstalled and re installed the services successfully before.. without restarting the pc..